# Angular Jquery slideToggle/Up popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When the the green popup is open and then when you click the blue one it closes green and opens blue popup.

[image: to give some visuals]

The links

```
      <li><a id="contactBtn" class="active" href="javascript: void(0)" ng-click="showForm()">Kontakt</a></li>
  <li><a id="faceBtn" class="active" href="javascript: void(0)" ng-click="showFace()">Facebook</a></li>
```

And the AngularApp

```
$scope.showForm = function () {
  $('.contactRow').slideToggle();
};
$scope.closeForm = function () {
  $('.contactRow').slideUp();
};

$scope.showFace = function () {
  $('.facebook').slideToggle();
};
$scope.closeFace = function () {
  $('.facebook').slideUp();
};
```

I also have added a little bit jQuery to make a lightbox effect

```
      $("#contactBtn, #faceBtn").click(function(){
    $('#overlay').animate({'opacity':'0.7'}, 300, 'linear');
      $('#overlay').css('display','block');
    });

  $('#closeForm, #closeFace').click(function(){
    $('#overlay').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
      $('#overlay').css('display','none');
    });
  });
```

Now is there a good way to bind these all together, lets say you open green(lightbox effect animation) then you decide to click on blue it removes the green window and lightbox effect stays and blue opens and when you click blue link again it closes+(lightbox).

Or I'm making things too complicated.

EDIT :
New AngularApp

```
// onclick event handlers
$scope.showForm = function () {
  $('.contactRow').slideToggle();
    if($(".facebook").is(":visible"))  
  {
    $('.facebook').hide(); 
  }  

};
$scope.closeForm = function () {
  $('.contactRow').slideUp();
};

//FACEBOOK
$scope.showFace = function () {
  $('.facebook').slideToggle();
  if($(".contactRow").is(":visible"))  
  {
    $('.contactRow').hide(); 
  }  
};
$scope.closeFace = function () {
  $('.facebook').slideUp();
};
```

When you press facebook link once the popup opens and when you press it again but the lightbox effect made with jquery wont go away until I press X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another method other than slide toogle.check if the form is visible or not
Try something like this

```
if($(".contactRow").is(":visible"))  
  {
    $('.contactRow').hide(); 
  }     
else
  {
   $('.facebook').hide(); 
   $('.contactRow').show(); 
  }
```

You can do the same for facebook class also.Check if it is visible or invisible and then act accordingly ..

Comment: I updated the post at bottom with the new code which works but the problem is once I press Facebook link to open and then click Facebook link again it closes but the lightbox effect remains. Any idea how to incorporate the code so that it disappears?

Comment: When you hide the face book class then make overlay display as none  $('#overlay').css('display','none');